# Align customized range slider with adjacent inline elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

Following [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/creating-custom-css-range-slider-javascript-upgrades/) tutorial I was able to create a range slider and customize it to my needs

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

for (var input of inputs)
{
    console.log("processing")
    input.oninput = progressScript
    input.oninput()
}

function progressScript() {
    const sliderValue = this.value;
    this.style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, white ${sliderValue}%, rgb(44, 160, 255) ${sliderValue}%)`;
}
```

```css
body
{
    background: rgb(41, 62, 72);
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
}

input[type=range] {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
   width: 300px;
   height: 10px;
   background: rgb(44, 160, 255);
   border-radius: 15px;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background: rgb(41, 62, 72);
   border: 3px solid white;
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgb(41, 62, 72);
}

div
{
   height: 30px;
   margin-top: 30px;
   margin-bottom: 30px;
}

span
{
   margin-left: 10px;
   margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <p>Skills:</p>

    <div>
        <span>C++</span>
        <input type="range" name="volume" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <span>C#/.NET</span>
        <input type="range" name="cowbell" />
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Now I would like to make sure the centerline of my spans are aligned with the centerline of the range slider, such that the final result looks like this, without the red line (included only for clarity):

How can I get it so that the two inline elements are aligned from their centerlines?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a class to your divs that wraps your elements  (in the row)  and add those properties to them:

```css
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
```

It will look like this :

[image]

In the new code, I have named the divs class simply  `container` :

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

for (var input of inputs)
{
    console.log("processing")
    input.oninput = progressScript
    input.oninput()
}

function progressScript() {
    const sliderValue = this.value;
    this.style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, white ${sliderValue}%, rgb(44, 160, 255) ${sliderValue}%)`;
}
```

```css
body
{
    background: rgb(41, 62, 72);
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.container{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
   
}

input[type=range] {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
   width: 300px;
   height: 10px;
   background: rgb(44, 160, 255);
   border-radius: 15px;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background: rgb(41, 62, 72);
   border: 3px solid white;
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgb(41, 62, 72);
}

div
{
   height: 30px;
   margin-top: 30px;
   margin-bottom: 30px;
}

span
{
   margin-left: 10px;
   margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <p>Skills:</p>

    <div class='container'>
        <span>C++</span>
        <input type="range" name="volume" />
    </div>

    <div class='container'>
        <span>C#/.NET</span>
        <input type="range" name="cowbell" />
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

And if you don't want to use flex you can use [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position), you can add:

```css
    position: relative;
    top: -7px;
```

Into your `input[type=range]` selector.

Now it will look like this :

[image]

And you can change how much the inputs will go up or down by changing the `top: -7px;` amount of pixels.

Here is the updated code :

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

for (var input of inputs)
{
    console.log("processing")
    input.oninput = progressScript
    input.oninput()
}

function progressScript() {
    const sliderValue = this.value;
    this.style.background = `linear-gradient(to right, white ${sliderValue}%, rgb(44, 160, 255) ${sliderValue}%)`;
}
```

```css
body
{
    background: rgb(41, 62, 72);
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
}

input[type=range] {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
   width: 300px;
   height: 10px;
   position: relative;
   top: -7px;
   background: rgb(44, 160, 255);
   border-radius: 15px;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   background: rgb(41, 62, 72);
   border: 3px solid white;
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px rgb(41, 62, 72);
}

div
{
   height: 30px;
   margin-top: 30px;
   margin-bottom: 30px;
}

span
{
   margin-left: 10px;
   margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <p>Skills:</p>

    <div class='container'>
        <span>C++</span>
        <input type="range" name="volume" />
    </div>

    <div class='container'>
        <span>C#/.NET</span>
        <input type="range" name="cowbell" />
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there perhaps a way to do this that does not involve using flex? I'm trying to keep things simple here...

Comment: There are a lot of ways to achieve this without using Flex, In my personal opinion using flex keeps things simple, do you have any other method preferred? you can do it via position/grid or js for example (I don't think that doing it via js will be less complicated )

Comment: I'm just trying to avoid using pre-made CSS layouts for the time being as I am a beginner in the world of CSS/HTML and web design. Trying to get the basics first. I'll do some more digging and probably accept your answer if I don't find anything a little more straightforward/easier to understand. I'm aware your answer is probably the right one.

Comment: I have updated my answer and given you another option to achieve this by using position instead of flex, is this what you meant by *avoid using pre-made CSS layouts ?*

Comment: Close, except I would have preferred to not have a hardcoded offset like `-7px` as I may be changing the dimensions, paddings and/or margin of the range slider... Anyway I'll accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @user32882: "*I'm just trying to avoid using pre-made CSS layouts for the time being as I am a beginner*" - you have every right to use whatever technique you prefer, but: **1**. CSS flex is *not* "pre-made," **2**. I don't see any reason to use or learn the older solutions to your problem that were only necessary because CSS flex, and grid, layouts didn't exist. And, In addition, **3**. your complaint "*I would [prefer] to not have a hardcoded offset*" is exactly the problem for which flex and grid were (finally, eventually...!) created to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You may also do this

```css
div > * {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

`div > *` means all direct childern of that div. And then

```css
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
```

will make both span and input vertically centre of the div.